# Automatically expire and delete record in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm am fairly new to android and I made an app that creates, modifies and deletes users using SQLite. What I want to do is that after, lets say a week after a user is created, it deletes itself without the administrator having to do it himself.
Is there a way to do this? Thank you for your answers

Comment: Consider if you actually need to accomplish the deletion of the user entry at a particular time, or if it would be enough to achieve the same effect to delete it on next usage of the app if it is found to be past its expiration date.  You could even go a step further and remove it when queried if found to be expired...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to store a creationDate with the user then make a service that runs sql command, let's say each night, to see wich users are more than a week old.

I don't think there is a way that the database detects it alone.

Here is a link about [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) it's usefull to run background stuff at set times.

Comment: You could potentially use the AlarmManager class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule running your SQL command even if your app isn't running.
Edit: theyouishere beat me to it!

Comment: Yes, i just edited my post and then i saw your comment lol. AlarmManager is the best practice in this case i guess

Answer (score 0):

So I created two rows in my SQLite DB and made a timestamp with the current date.
The second row was a TEXT and I made the user pick the expiration date using a CalendarView. 
To delete the row I used the delete method. Since this method return an int value, I made it launch a Toast to say how many rows where deleted